# Spring cloud stream with GCP Pubsub - disable check for existing topic

Tags: spring, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

I have a PubSub subscription in GCP Project `A`, and a Spring Cloud Stream app running in `A`.

That PubSub subscription in `A` references a Topic `foo` in GCP Project `B`. That application currently has only access to that subscription (but not to that topic in `B`). AFAIK this should be a valid config.

However, it seems that `PubSubChannelProvisioner` wants to make sure that the topic exists, and throws an exception:

> Failed to create consumer binding; retrying in 30 seconds
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException:
>   Non-existing 'projects/A/topics/foo' topic.
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.makeSureTopicExists(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:124)
>   at

Is there an option to disable that? Or is it necessary to give that app access to Topic `foo` in `A`?

Comment: Can you share pieces of your code?

Comment: Still I face the same issue. Do you have any solution for this now?

Answer (score 0):

That is a valid topic and subscription config. However, there currently isn't a way to disable the topic existence check in PubSubChannelProvider. Could you [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues) for this on the spring-cloud-gcp repository?